# Passing parameters on slim routes

Tags: php, parameters, routes, slim

I'm trying to pass some parameters on a slim route.
I got this function in a file called Usuarios.php

```
function IniciarSesion($app)
{
    VerificarParametrosRequeridos(array('NombreUsuario', 'Contrasena'));

    $json = $app->request->getBody();
    $datapost = json_decode($json, TRUE);
}
```

And I got this route on a index.php that requires the Usuarios.php file

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'DbConnect.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->pdo = new DbConnect();   

require 'app/Usuarios.php';
$app->post('/usuarios/login','IniciarSesion');
```

And I want to pass to the route that call the IniciarSesion function, the $app var declare in index.php

is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Hey as you can use `getInstance()` static method.

Check it here:

http://docs.slimframework.com/configuration/names-and-scopes/

```
<?php
use Slim\Slim;

$app = new Slim();
$app->get('/foo', 'foo');
function foo() {
    $app = Slim::getInstance();
    $app->render('foo.php');
}
```

Comment: Link to docs are for Slim 3. Looking at his code OP is using Slim 2.

Comment: Nice catch. Edited answer.

Comment: It still not working, when I am trying to get the instance, I got this error message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Slim' not found

Comment: What about `$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();` ? :)